# What exactly makes a non-blocking socket block? The possible danger of using epoll() in edge-triggered mode

Tags: linux, sockets, nonblocking, epoll, epollet

Say we want to write a server to handle multiple clients by using [epoll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) in edge-triggered mode.
While using `epoll()` in edge-triggered mode, whenever the server receives the `EPOLLOUT` or `EPOLLIN` event, **it has to write or read until it receives `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`**.

Say a client connects and sends a VEEEERY long message. Now the server has to read it until it gets get `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`.

**Can the server be sure `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN` is received after some reasonable amount of time and it doesn't end up reading gigabytes of data from that client, while all other clients are waiting?**

This isn't just a Yes or No question. I'm looking forward to understanding how this blocking is controlled on the OS level.

Comment: No. It could starve the other connections. You should read some limited amount and then go on to the next ready event. This socket will be ready next time around the polling loop.

Comment: @user207421 so you suggest reading a limited amount out of each ready socket in a loop until all sockets block?

Comment: You don't have to read/write everything immediately, but `epoll()` won't tell you that it's ready to use until you do. So you'll need to keep track of this state in your application.